# Chinese Adjustable 60W soldering iron problem

Tags: soldering, hacking, soldering-iron-station

I bought a 60W Adjustable soldering iron from China last year. I think it's designed to run at 220v because it is not hot enough when connected to 120v. It measures about 200 degree C. So I decided to see if I can fix it. there is a 500k pot and a 100k resistor. I guess by changing this voltage resistor, it probably will increase the temperature. so I changed the 100k to 75k, and measured the temperature again, and it didn't go up. then I changed the 100k to 500k, and it went up to 230 degree at max, still not hot enough.

There are my question:
1, there are 4 terminals for this soldering iron. I think 2 of them are the heating lines and 2 are the temperature sensor lines. Can I ignore the controlling circuit, and connect 120v ac directly to the 2 heating lines? because the adjustable temperature circuit is useless.

2, It has a lm358 op-amp and a TO-92 package 600V 97A6 M922 Bidirectional Thyristor. This thyristor is tiny. Can it really output 60W??

3, the circuit pcb trace is very thin on the ac lines, is this bad design?

Comment: Not having a proper label as to what voltage is for should be the first red flag. It can only go downhills from there on

Comment: J u s t   d o n ' t!  You are randomly changing parts in a circuit you don't understand, and that connects to 120VAC.  Powering the heating element directly might work, or it might work just long enough to go BANG!  Worst case, it isn't intended to be connected to 120V at all, and you've now got a soldering iron tip at 120V - a good way to kill whatever you try to solder or to kill yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the soldering iron is rated for 220 V and you're using it at 120 V then bypassing the temperature control circuit is useless. The control circuit will just apply maximum power to the iron until it has reached the desired temperature which in your case never happens.

A 220V 60 W iron will be around 800 ohms (measure that !) so at 120 V it will consume a power of 18 Watt. For an iron with a very small tip that might be enough but for a 60 W rated iron it's not enough power.

The Thyristor does not output 60 W, it SWITCHES 60 W. A proper thyristor will dissipate maybe 1 W (probably much less) in this situation.

60 W at 240 V gives a current of 270 mA, you don't need wide copper traces for that.

Comment: it measure 714 ohm; my 20w measures 600, and my other 60w measures 300.

Comment: That confirms it, this is a soldering iron for 240 V !